# How to get a next available date value where required date value is NULL while joining two tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an issue while joining two tables in BigQuery. Please see the attached image. Table1 has the End date of company filings and table2 has historical stock prices. The end date is the same for most of the companies in the last five years, in one year(30/09/2018) was a weekend so did not have a stock price for that day. So how to get a value from the next available date in Table2 while joining both tables on Table1.date = Table2.date. can anyone let me know how to do perform a query in BigQuery?

Thank you,
Shiva

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the next available stock price from your table2 and put it in the share price from the table1 when it is weekend? More practically it would be, in table1 for 30/09/2018 the share price would be 50, is this right?

Comment: Hi, Yes it is, i would like to have a share price on Monday's or next available share price in my Table1. Please let me know how can i do a query in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your clarification in the comment section I was able to create a query using StandardSQL to achieve what you aim.

I have used the built-in function [LEAD()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#lead), which returns the next row's value based in a *partition and/or order*. Below is the query:

```
WITH table1 AS (
SELECT DATE(2015,09,30) as end_date, 20 as share_price UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2016,09,30) as end_date, 30 as share_price UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2017,09,30) as end_date, 40 as share_price UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2018,09,30) as end_date, NULL as share_price UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2019,09,30) as end_date, 60 as share_price 
), 
table2 AS(
SELECT DATE(2015,09,30) as date, 20 as share_price UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2016,09,30) as date, 30 as share_price UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2017,09,30) as date, 40 as share_price UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2018,09,30) as date, NULL as share_price UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2018,10,01) as date, 50 as share_price UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2019,09,30) as date, 60 as share_price 
),
table2_ref AS (
SELECT date, 
IF(share_price IS NULL, LEAD(share_price,1) OVER (ORDER BY date), share_price) AS share_price 

#this following column is not necessary, it is just to check which null values were modified
,IF(share_price IS NULL, "got the next available value", "kept the value") AS check

FROM table2
ORDER BY date
)
SELECT a.date, a.share_price FROM table2_ref a INNER JOIN table1 b ON a.date = b.end_date
```

And the output,

[image]

Notice that I have used a column ***check*** within ***table2_ref***, in order to follow which values were changed from *null to the next available price*. Thus, it is just a flag that can be in the output to check, but you can suppress this column in your code (as I did in the output image above).

Comment: Thank you so much, let me try with my data.